# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myAppUserDetailsService';

Tags: security, spring-boot, autowired, mockmvc

**Spring boot 1.5.3 project with test user-registry on H2 in memory DB**

This is the **Error Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myAppUserDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SMRTUserService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userInfoDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SMRTUserDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/temp/SMRT/target/test-classes/data.sql]: ....
```

Can someone help me to understand the problem? I can't solve this errors.

---

**Test Controller**

```
public class CustomerControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void testShow() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/customer/list")
        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

---

**AbstractControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends AbstractTest {

    @Autowired protected MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;
    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .dispatchOptions(true)
            .addFilters(filterChainProxy).build();
    }
}
```

---

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private SMRTUserService myAppUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myAppUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

---

**SMRTUSerService**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class SMRTUserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired private ISMRTUserDAO userInfoDAO;
    @Autowired private SMRTUserRepository smrtuserRepository;
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your Exception already explains pretty well what the problem is:

```
Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/temp/SMRT/target/test-classes/data.sql]: ....
```

I asume you're importing some test data for your tests? There must be an error in your SQL statements.

Comment: I only have a **src/test/resources/data.sql** with INSERT statement (no CREATE table statement, and I don't have a CREATE table .sql file).

Comment: At the end of the Stacktrace there are: **Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ROLE" not found; SQL statement:** I try to put create code inside, but I find a way to generate it automatically (ddl create).

Comment: There you have it. 

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` in your properties should do that trick

Comment: I know, but the error is always the same, there are something more that give me troubles!

Comment: Do you have an entity class for the role table? Can you provide the model code and your properties?

Comment: It would appear to really be a SQL error hidden in the stacktrace, Thank's a lot Christian

Answer (score 0):

if you are using keycloak for the  authentification . you might get this error .
jhipster by default gives you 8090 as auth server , so you have to change it

Solution : 1 - start your keycloak server

```
       2 - go to your jhipster project main->ressources->config->application.yml
```

change **issuer ui** by the port where  your keycloak server is running : for example :   issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo

hope that was helpfull